# I cant get the session

Tags: sessions

I m beginner on drupal, and i have a problem with session.

I created a custom form submission inside the *clubs* module.

```php
namespace Drupal\idan_login\Form;

// Form submission handler.
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Get the submitted values.
    $values = $form_state->getValues();
    $username = $values['username'];
    $password = $values['password'];
    // Tentez d'authentifier l'utilisateur.
    
    
    // Attempt to check infos the user.
    $uid = \Drupal::service('user.auth')->authenticate($username, $password);
  
    // Check if authentication was successful.
    if ($uid) {
      // User authenticated successfully. 
      
        // Load the user entity.
        $user = User::load($uid);
         
       // Check if the user has the "club idan" role.
        if ($user->hasRole('club_idan')) {
          
          $_SESSION['has_subscribed'] = TRUE;
          // User authenticated successfully and has the "club idan" role.
          \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus(t("Vous avez été connecté avec succès")); 

            
          // Redirect to "/fr/clubs".
          $response = new RedirectResponse('/fr/clubs'); 
          $response->send(); 
          
        }
        else {
         
          unset($_SESSION['has_subscribed']);
          // User authentication failed due to missing role.
          \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t("Vous n'avez pas le rôle requis pour accéder à ce site"));
          // Redirect to a different page.
          $form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromUri('internal:/fr/club-idan'));
 
        }
      
    }
    else {
      // Authentication failed.
      unset($_SESSION['has_subscribed']);

      // Display an error message.
      \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t("Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe invalide. Veuillez réessayer"));
      // Redirect back to the same page. 
      $form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromUri('internal:/fr/club-idan'));
      
    }
    
    // Rebuild the form to display any updated messages.
    //$form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  }
```

And i create a new custom module named "custom_access_check" to grant access to a page when the "has_subscribed" value has been set for the current session.

```php
// custom_access_check.module

use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view_alter().
 */
function custom_access_check_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  // Start the session if it's not already started.
  \Drupal::service('session')->start();
  // Check if the node being viewed is of type 'your_content_type'.  
  
  if (!empty($build['#node']->getType()) && $build['#node']->getType() == 'page') {
    
    if ($alias_path == '/clubs') {
      // Check if the session variable "has_subscribed" is set. 
      
      if (!isset($_SESSION['has_subscribed']) || !$_SESSION['has_subscribed']) {
        // If user has not subscribed, deny access to the content.
        throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException();
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

`$_SESSION['has_subscribed']`  contains `NULL`.

If someone has the some situation or has any idea for this problem?

Comment: You should always set the redirect in $form_state. If you send the client away before Drupal is finished it can't set the session cookie.

Comment: Also set `$build['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'session';` for the content type in the node view hook.

Comment: Thank you, that work good.
I added the function in the node view hook and i make return vers url using $form_state